# How long forever was running

Tags: forever

How to tell how long the process controlled by forever has been running (when it is still running). Without restarting the process. Basically I look for something analogous to `uptime` command in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running `forever list` gives you uptime of each script. You should try pm2, personally, I feel its better than forever for running scripts.